# Получить два разных объекта (либо один тип, либо второй) от метода

Tags: mvc, java

При реализации принципа MVC в Java столкнулся с необходимостью получения от одного из классов (объекта, его метода) Model объекта либо одного (1), либо второго (2) типа.(1) и (2) абсолютно разные типы. Создание объектов (1) либо (2) происходит в классе Model в зависимости от результата анализа и обработки переданных ему данных.

Comment: Наверное я ничего не понимаю, но что мешает методу Model.m1 возвращать объект type1, а Model.m2 возвращать объект type2?

Comment: Будьте добры описать ситуацию, в которой это необходимо. Очень интересно.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы сами не знаете, что Вам нужно. Репозитории из базы возвращают объекты "абсолютно разных типов", но это пока никому не мешало их использовать.
Попробуйте сделать вопрос менее абстрактным, может в реальности всё гораздо проще окажется.

Comment: Решена - Generics:

В класс Model включил поле:
private Container<?> result;

Класс Container может иметь любой состав полей, например:
private T simple;
private T array[];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вариант 1:

```
public class TF extends JFrame implements Configurable, Testable {

    private CommonInterface common = null;

    // создаем "общий" интерфейс - контейнер
    public TF() {
        // create new common instance
        common = new CommonInterface() {
            @Override
            public Configurable getConfigurable() {
                return TF.this;
            }

            @Override
            public Testable getTestable() {
                return TF.this;
            }
        };

        // использование
        configure(getCommon().getConfigurable());
        test(getCommon().getTestable());
    }

    // возвращаем интерфейс доступа к другим интерфейсам
    public CommonInterface getCommon() {
        return common;
    }

    // методы которые работают с отдельными интерфейсами
    private void test(Testable testable) {
        testable.doTest();
    }

    private void configure(Configurable configurable) {
        configurable.doChange();
    }

    // имплементация (в данном примере наш класс сам выступает контейнером функционала для остальных)
    @Override
    public void doChange() {
        System.out.println("change");
    }

    @Override
    public void doTest() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}

interface CommonInterface {
    Configurable getConfigurable();

    Testable getTestable();
}

interface Configurable {
    public void doChange();
}

interface Testable {
    public void doTest();
}
```

вариант 2:

```
public class TF extends JFrame implements CommonInterface {

    // использование
    public TF() {
        configure(getCommon());
        test(getCommon());
    }

    // методы которые используют разные интерфейсы одного и того же обьекта
    private void test(Testable c) {
        c.doTest();
    }

    private void configure(Configurable c) {
        c.doChange();
    }

    // метод который возвращает ссылку сразу на 2 интерфейса
    // в данном примере оставлен только для наглядности    
    public CommonInterface getCommon() {
        return this;
    }

    // имплементация. в принципе она могла быть в других обьектах
    @Override
    public void doChange() {
        System.out.println("change");
    }

    @Override
    public void doTest() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}

interface CommonInterface extends Configurable, Testable {
}

interface Configurable {
    public void doChange();
}

interface Testable {
    public void doTest();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть несколько способов решения указанной вами проблемы:

1) Возвращать некую обертку вокруг объекта type1 и type2, типа:

```
class MyWrapper
{
    private Type1 myType1;
    private Type2 myType2;
}
```

Это скорее в стиле C, чем в стиле Java. В стиле Java подойдет второй способ:

2) Возвращать общий интерфейс, например `MyReturnable`

```
class Type1 implements MyReturnable {}
class Type2 implements MyReturnable {}
```

3) Самый идеальный конечно вариант когда оба ваших типа имеют одного и того же предка `MyType`, который вы и будете возвращать:

```
class Type1 extends MyType {}
class Type2 extends MyType {}
```

Comment: См. условие: (1) и (2) абсолютно разные типы - никакого общего интерфейса.

Comment: @rvm ну дык продекларируй общий интерфейс - делов то...

Comment: @rvm, как мега изврат возвращайте методом объект класса Object, но я до сих пор не могу понять зачем и в какой ситуации это надо.

Comment: @Barmaley и @Viacheslav, с точки зрения результата мое решение его достигло, с точки зрения Java, если возможность предоставлена, то почему бы ею не использовать. Ваша критика отностительно нарушения принципов ООП необоснованна или пока не доказана:
В моем решении, при принятии решения Controller через instanceof определяет полученный тип, и уже в зависимости от его результата формирует request на Jsp1 или Jsp2.
При реализации Вашего варианта не тем ли самым методом - instanceof придется руководствоваться Controller-у при определении конкретного типа полученного объекта (Type1) или (Type2)?

Comment: @rvm, я не критиковал, мне было действительно интересно, ибо с таким я не сталкивался. Как вариант - можно написать свой Exception, если при обработке метода в контроллере он перехватывается - обрабатываем его и посылаем на Jsp2, если метод выполняется корректно - на Jsp1, это работает только в случае если возвращенный объект для дальнейшей работы не требуется.